# open_http: 403 Forbidden (OpenURI::HTTPError)

Tags: ruby, api, https, open-uri

I am trying to pull data from my Google+ API, using this script:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

google_api_key = 'put your google api key here'
page_id = '105672627985088123672'

data = open("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/#{page_id}?key=#{google_api_key}").read    
obj = JSON.parse(data)

puts obj['plusOneCount'].to_i
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
/Users/xng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:346:in `open_http': 403 Forbidden (OpenURI::HTTPError)
    from /Users/xng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:769:in `buffer_open'
    from /Users/xng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
    from /Users/xng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
    from /Users/xng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
    from /Users/xng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
    from /Users/xng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:671:in `open'
    from /Users/xng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
    from gplus.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure what is wrong here, any help would be great.

Comment: When you run the script are you sure that you are actually sending your API key? Did you copy it right? Is it valid?

Comment: yup i got the api key right, just didnt include it up there.

Comment: Ah,my bad. I just did a regeneration of the API Keys and used the newly generated ones. It works now.

Comment: @jenn add your own answer, and then accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to regenerate the API key.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like your google API key doesn't match the one that google have in their servers. So you need to make sure that you are using the right key. is it a private or free service ?